# how to reload a view without clearing its cache in ionic. $state.go isn’t refreshing a cache view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-v1

I have 2 views:
`view1` and `view2`.

I want to go from `view1` to `view2`, and reload the `view2` data.
But I don't want to clear the cache of `view2`.

So my question is, without clearing cache of `view2`, how to reload `view2`?

I am using

```
$state.go('view2',{reload: true});
```

Comment: Simple...store data in local storage and redirect on another page reload the page.....and get data back....

Comment: I suggest you use `sessionStorage` to store your data. `sessionStorage`  will be clear when you close the tab

Comment: try `$state.go('inbox',{reload: false});`

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal  "view2" is a cached view . i want to reload "view2" without clearing its cache .